# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: selenium, java

I am trying to do this: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/

Below is the screenshot taken from eclipse

```
package com.stack.tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class PerformanceTesting {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
            driver.quit();
        } }
```

Below is the error code taken while running:

```
E:\stackoverflow\src\test\java\com\stack\tests>javac -cp selenium-serv
er-standalone-2.52.0.jar PerformanceTesting.java

E:\stackoverflow\src\test\java\com\stack\tests>set classpath=%classpat
h%;.;

E:\stackoverflow\src\test\java\com\stack\tests>java -cp .;selenium-ser
ver-standalone-2.52.0.jar PerformanceTesting
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PerformanceTesting (w
rong name: com/stack/tests/PerformanceTesting)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Does somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: I see com.stackovfl.tests in the eclipse excerpt and com/stack/tests in the error code.  Might that be part of the problem?

Comment: I changed it. I added wrongly. It was my company name so changed it to stack overflow.

Comment: Have you added the Selenium Standalone JAR file to your JAVA project?

Answer (score 7):

Have you added the Selenium Standalone JAR to your Java Project in Eclipse?

In Eclipse,

- Expand your project
- Right click on Referenced Libraries.
- Point to Build Path
- Select Configure Build Path
- In the dialog box that appears remove any old libraries, add new ones
  and check and make sure you have added [Selenium JAR](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Once you have added the required libraries to the project try running again. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is occur only when `selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar` is not added or the path is not correct. Please add `selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar` again or set your path again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Method1:
Try to add GUAVA jar in your build path.
please go through the link for this jar
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release23

If you are using MAVEN project have that dependency
please go through the link for this dependency
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/16.0.1

Method2:
Add your jars into the classpath
Location:JRE-LIB-EXT(place your jars here)
Now jre will call all these jars automatically.
Add your all external jars such as selenium jars under class path not module path